# Como adicionar uma objeto javascript em um option do select recebido dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

Qual o melhor caminho para adicionar uma informação no value do  sendo que eu recebo um object de forma dinâmica.

O código atual está da seguinte forma (Notem o **_options[i] | json**):

```
<ion-item *ngIf="_type.indexOf('select') > -1 || _type.indexOf('checkbox') > -1 || _type.indexOf('radiobutton') > -1">
    <ion-label floating>{{_title}}</ion-label>
    <ion-select title={{_type}} [multiple]="_type === 'select' ? false : null || _type === 'checkbox' ? true : null || _type === 'radiobutton' ? false : null"
        [(ngModel)]="answer" (ionChange)="inputPopulate($event, _id, answer)">
        <ion-option value="{{_options[i] | json}}" *ngFor="let option of _options; let i = index">{{_options[i].answer}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

O _options é algo do tipo:
[image: Opções do multselect]

Codigo da tela responsavel por acrescentar a opção selecionada ao this._obj

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let item of slide.sections">
            <h2 class="slide-title" [innerHTML]="item.name"></h2>
            <div class="board-item">
              <p [innerHTML]="item.description" class="slide-description"></p>
              <ion-list class="form-body">
                <form #form="ngForm" class="form">
                  <div *ngFor="let question of item.questions; let x = index">
                    {{ question.answers }}
                    <custom-input (value)="listenerAnswer($event, question._id, 0)" [id]="question._id" type="{{ question.type | lowercase }}"
                      [options]=question.answers title="{{ question.question }}"></custom-input>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </ion-list>
            </div>
```

Ao selecionar uma ou varias opções do select e pressionar OK, o seguinte metodo é executado:

```
listenerAnswer(value, questionId, conditional?: boolean) {
        try {
          const data = JSON.parse(value.data);
          this.obj[value.id] = data.answer ? data.answer : data;
        } catch (e) {
          const data = value.data;
          this.obj[value.id] = data;
        }
        this.answers = {
          personId: this.personId,
          answers: this.obj,
          decision: this.decision,
        };
      }
```

Veja oque acontece ao enviar a requisição:
Informações como: \n e \ são adicionadas a string e isso está me atrapalhando bastante
[image: Payload]

No mongoDB as informações estão sendo salvas com os \n e :

[image: Mongodb]

Podem me ajudar a encontrar um caminho mais adequado para tratar desse impasse?

Informações extra:

No momento da escolha do select:

```
inputPopulate(data, id, target) {
    const value = data.toString();
    this.value.emit({
      id,
      data: value,
      target,
    });
  }
```

[image: Console log do inputPopulaate]

Método que realiza o post.

```
sendAnswers(data): Observable<any> {

        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this.http.post(`/answer`, data, headers );
      }
```

Comment: Sugiro trartar esses dados antes de salvar no MongoDB, tirar os `\n` e `\"`. E por que você precisa do objeto inteiro como valor de cada opção? Apenas o `_id` não basta?

Comment: Então, eu preciso da resposta do usuário e preciso identificar a question referente aquela resposta.
Sobre tratar antes. Estou tentando fazer isso mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso pela regex.

Comment: Coloca o codigo inves de imagens é bem mais fácil pra  alguem te ajudar.

Comment: Atualizei as informações. Espero que possam me ajudar a encontrar um caminho viável.

Comment: @Costamilam Resolvi o problema seguinte sua orientação. Agora é adicionado somente o _id.